# How to use QUploader (Quasar-Framework) with websockets?

Tags: websocket, vue.js, vuejs2, feathersjs, quasar-framework

QUploader is documented [here](http://quasar-framework.org/components/uploader.html) and here is its [code](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/blob/v0.14.7/src/components/uploader/QUploader.vue).

I am trying to get QUploader (Quasar-framework version 0.14.7) working uploading images to a featherjs 'service' on external server, basically following along [this example](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/advanced/file-uploading.html).

How do I use QUploader with websockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to make feathersjs upload work without Quasar, that didn't work, but I am able to make Quasar work with a normal Express multer upload.

You just use add `:upload-factory="uploadFile"` to the q-uploader component.

The method goes like this: `uploadFile(file, updateProgress)`

And you can do whatever with the file what you want, and you can calculate the progress and call `updateProgress(calculatedProgress)` with calculatedProgress going from 0.0 to 1.0.

(Just make sure you have feathers-client wokring through websockets, then use Axios or something else on the client to upload it through websockets)

It's all explained [here](https://quasar-framework.org/components/uploader.html#Upload-Factory)